# MVVM: Binding to ListBox.SelectedItem isn't being updated?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

How do I bind a view model property to the ListBox.SelectedItem property?

I have created a simple MVVM demo to try to figure this one out. My view model has these properties:

```
private ObservableCollection<DisneyCharacter> p_DisneyCharacters;
public ObservableCollection<DisneyCharacter> DisneyCharacters
{
    get { return p_DisneyCharacters; }

    set
    {
        p_DisneyCharacters = value;
        base.FirePropertyChangedEvent("DisneyCharacters");
    }
}

private DisneyCharacter p_SelectedItem;
public DisneyCharacter SelectedItem
{
    get { return p_SelectedItem; }

    set
    {
        p_SelectedItem = value;
        base.FirePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

I want to bind the SelectedItem property to the item selected in the list box. Here is the XAML for the list box:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterTemplate}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisneyCharacters}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selectedtem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Here is my problem: The view model SelectedItem property isn't being updated when I change the selection in the list box.

I did a test where I temporarily replaced the view model SelectedItem property with a SelectedIndex property, and I bound that to the ListBox.SelectedIndex property. That property updated fine--it's just the SelectedItem property that I can't get to work.

So, how do I fix the SelectedItem binding? Thanks for your help.

Comment: A good example of how to use a list box in MVVM. Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Well, there it is, big as life. In the XAML I was binding to a view model property called:

```
Selectedtem
       ^^
```

Unfortunately, the actual name is `SelectedItem`. So this code actually works--I solved the problem early this afternoon and then spent the rest of the afternoon and all evening scouring the web, before I noticed the spelling error.

My wife told me at 3:00 this afternoon, "*You know, it's going to turn out to be something small.*" And so it did--a missing letter `I`. Well, at least I can go to bed now.

Comment: To help you find these problems sooner, if you debug your app you should see a WPF binding error in the Output window of Visual Studio, indicating that the property "Selectedtem" doesn't exist. Hopefully that would help you to track down this sort of error quicker in the future.

Comment: I wish I knew about the binding errors in the output window a year ago when I started Silverlight development. Just when you start to think you are a decent developer...

Comment: @BoxerBucks, I don't think you get **any** notifications or logs for failed bindings in SilverLight.

Comment: @Sam - You should get a binding error in the output window of Visual Studio. It's there if a binding fails. Look at Andy's comment at the top of this chain.

Comment: In this situation you should probably be using a capital letter on you view model public property. Then you know you are binding to the property. As mentioned above, use ctrl-f & search for 'binding' in the output window at run time. This will give you the error if a binding has failed in WPF