# Clarification on binding Listbox.SelectedItem in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a `ListBox` in one of my user controls in which I would like to get the `SelectedItem`, to be used in the ViewModel. The `ListBox` is composed of `TextBlocks`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384369/mvvm-binding-to-listbox-selecteditem) is pretty much a straight up answer to my question, but I don't understand where `DisneyCharacter` (his collection type) comes from, or how it relates to the `ListBox`.

Would mine be of type `TextBlock`?

XAML for `ListBox` as requested:

```
<ListBox Margin="14,7,13,43" Name="commandListBox" Height="470" MinHeight="470" MaxHeight="470" Width="248" >
               <TextBlock Text="Set Output" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
               <TextBlock Text="Clear Output" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
               <TextBlock Text="Follow Left Tape Edge" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
               <TextBlock Text="Follow Right Tape Edge" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
               <TextBlock Text="Follow Tape Center" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" /></ListBox>
```

Comment: Are you filling the texblocks from Manually, or binding them to something? Post your xaml just for the listbox

Comment: I just manually filled them in xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output from a TextBlock is a string, you would bind to a string property, you would bind to a string in your ViewModel or code behind.

```
<ListBox SelectedItem = "{Binding myString}">
     .......
</ListBox>
```

Then in whatever your datacontext is set up a string Property like this

```
public string myString {get; set;}
```

Now whenever you click on an item, the text from that textblock will be in the myString variable.

if you were using MVVM model your property would look like this:

```
 private string _myString;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the myString property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string myString
    {
        get
        {
            return _myString;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_myString == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging("myString");
            _myString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("myString");
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Question for you... how come your setter isn't just: ` get { return _myString; } set { _myString = value; NotifyPropertyChange(() => MyString); }`?

Comment: In the setter I am checking if the value is the same first, so I don't call unnecessary ProepryChange's.  The rest is just preference, I am currently using the MVVM Light toolkit, and this is how the snippet is formatted, but it saves a ton of time typing.

Comment: I think this is working correctly, let me just try to implement it before I mark it as my answer. Thanks, by the way.